immuadmin login token_admin not found
Summary
For learning reasons i am running immudb in a Docker-Container based on the codenotary/immudb:latest - Image on my local machine.
When i try to login to immuadmin the token_auth file cannot be found.
What i want to achieve
I want to login to immuadmin, so that i can administer my immudb-instance.
What i tried (and how i failed)
With an up an running immudb-container on my machine i ran:
docker run -it --rm --network host --name immuadmin codenotary/immuadmin:latest login immudb

I was prompted for the password and gave the right password (when i give the wrong one, i am getting a different error message). I got following error message:
Password:
open /home/immu/token_admin: no such file or directory

I tried re-downloading and re-running all images (immuadmin and immudb) but still get the same error.
(first question on stackoverflow, sorry if i am missing needed Information)
Thank you,
Richhard
